# How to click on this 'a' tag with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I have this element

```
<p><a onclick="return getpermission(this);" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSub" class="btn btn-danger" data-endisbutton="" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSub','')">▼ Taylor-Swift-Bad-Blood-ft.-Kendrick-Lamar.srt</a> <strong>Subtitle (.SRT) </strong></p>
```

[on this page](https://www.rentanadviser.com/subtitles/getsubtitle.aspx?artist=Taylor%20Swift&song=Bad%20Blood%20ft.%20Kendrick%20Lamar) and I want to click on 'a' tag, so I found the 'a'tag element("elem") and ran (1st way) `elem.click()` then recieved

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a onclick="return getpermission(this);" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSub" class="btn btn-danger" data-endisbutton="" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSub','')">...</a> is not clickable at point (185, 668). Other element would receive the click: <a href="https://www.rentanadviser.com/downloads/kripto_video_protector_setup.exe" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">...</a>
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.82)
```

then ran (2nd way)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
action=ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(elem)#or the line below
action.move_to_element_with_offset(elem,0,80)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

then got error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.82)
```

then did (3rd way) in which first element of elem1 is the elem(a tag)

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click;", elem1)
```

which doesn't do anything.

btw this way I found 'elem'

```
links=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("p")
    for i in range(len(links)):
        strong=links[i].find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')
        if l(strong)>0:
            if links[i].find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')[0].text=='Subtitle (.SRT)':
                elem=links[i].find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[0]
```

Comment: please share all your relevant code

Answer (score 1):

If these buttons are what you are looking for: [DOM Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rUOn.png)

If you want only the `.srt` button:

```
srt_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='dowloadbuttons']//p//a[contains(text(), '.srt')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", srt_btn)
```

If you want click all the 4 buttons:

```
all_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='dowloadbuttons']//p//a[contains(@class, 'btn')]")))
for btn in all_btn:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need scroll the page to reach the element and then click on the element.

Use webdriverwait and wait for element to be clickable.

```
url = 'https://www.rentanadviser.com/subtitles/getsubtitle.aspx?artist=Taylor%20Swift&song=Bad%20Blood%20ft.%20Kendrick%20Lamar'
driver.get(url)
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
button1=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSub")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button1)
button1.click()
print("clicked")
time.sleep(10) #just to check whether downloading
```

You need to import below library.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```